# Prove that if $f$ is a continuous mapping of a compact metric space $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^k$, then $f(X)$ is closed and bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

> Prove that if $f$ is a continuous mapping of a compact metric space $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^k$, then $f(X)$ is closed and bounded.Thus $f$ is bounded.

*My Attempted Proof*

We have $f: X \to \mathbb{R}^k$. Since a continuous mapping of a compact metric space $A$ into an arbitrary metric space $B$ implies $f(A)$ is compact, it follows that $f(X)$ is compact in our case.

Let $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ be an open cover of $f(X)$. Then there exists finitely many indices such that $f(X) \subset V_{{\alpha}_1} \cup \ ... \ \cup V_{{\alpha}_n} $. Since we have each $V_{\alpha_{i}} \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, $\sup V_{\alpha_{i}}$ and $\inf V_{\alpha_{i}}$ exists in $\mathbb{R}^k$. Therefore $\sup f(X) \leq \sup \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{\alpha_{i}}$ and $\inf f(X) \geq \inf \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_{\alpha_{i}}$, so that $f(X)$ is bounded. It remains to be shown that $f(X)$ is closed.

Let $\gamma$ be a limit point of $f(X)$, and let $U_{\gamma}$ be a neighbourhood of $\gamma$. Then $U_{\gamma} \cap f(X) = C$ where $C$ is nonempty and $C \neq \{\gamma\}$ (by the definition of a limit point). Suppose $\gamma \not\in f(X)$, then there exists a $\epsilon > 0$ such that $U_{\gamma} = B_d(\gamma, \epsilon) \cap f(x) = \emptyset$ (where $B_d(\gamma, \epsilon)$ is the $\epsilon$-ball centered at $\gamma$ with respect to the metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$) . Thus $\gamma \in f(X)$ and we have $f(X)$ closed. $ \square$

---

Is my proof correct? If so how rigorous is it? Any comments on my proof writing skills and logical arguments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The statement "Since we have each $V_{\alpha_{i}} \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, $\sup V_{\alpha_{i}}$ and $\inf V_{\alpha_{i}}$ exists in $\mathbb{R}^k$" is false if $k=1$, and not meaningful if $k > 1$.

Comment: Ultimately you are just trying to prove that if $K \subset \mathbb R^k$ is compact, then $K$ is closed and bounded. A common way to prove the first part is to show "not closed" implies "not compact". For the second part cover $K$ by balls of a fixed radius and look at the finite subcover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f_i=\pi_i°f:X\rightarrow R$. Thus, $f_i$ is a continuous function and since $X$ is compact $f_i (X)$ is also compact. So  $f_i (X  )$ is closed and bounded. Now since $f ( X )\subseteq f_1 (X)×f_2 (X)×...×f_k ( X)$, $f (X)$ must be bounded. On the other hand, since $X$  is compact $f (X) $ is a compact subset of the hausdorff space $R^k$. Thus it is closed.

Answer (score 2):

Lets prove that $f(X)$ is compact. take an open cover $U_i$ of $f(X)$, notice that $f^{-1}(U_i)$is an open cover of $X$, therefore there is an finite subcover $f^{-1}V_i$ of $X$. Notice that $V_i$ is a finite subcover of $f(X)$.
Therefore $f(X)$ is compact, so it is closed and bounded.

Comment: Notice that when talking about whether a subspace $Y\subseteq X$ is compact it suffices to talk about "open covers" of $Y$ that consist of of sets that are $X$-open. (this is because the open sets of $Y$ are the intersections of open sets in $X$ with $Y$). I thought this subtleness could be confusing.

Comment: Well you assumed Heine-Borel, which seems to be the major part OP is  trying to prove.

Comment: I didn't assume Heine Borel, this is the trivial direction of Heine Borel.

Comment: I mean in the OP's attempted proof he was mainly trying to prove this "trivial direction" by hand.

Comment: @qidi Proof a compact set must be bounded and closed. If a set is not bounded any cover consisting of open balls clearly does not have a dinite subcover. If a set $A$  has a limit point $x$ that is not in $A$ then the set $X\setminus \overline{B(x,\frac{1}{n})}$ is an open cover that does not contain a finite subcover.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find a finite cover you need compactness. Otherwise this is not assured. Remember that in $\mathbb{R}^k$ there holds $f(X) $ compact $\iff$ $f(X)$ is closed and bounded $\iff$ There exists a finite subcovering for every open covering of $f(X)$. So after this first step you could already stop, since you know that $f(X)$ is compact and therefore bounded and closed.

Also the term $\sup V_{\alpha_i}$ does not make sense. You probably meant to say something like: There exists some $B_R(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ s.t. $ V_{\alpha_i} \subset B_R(0)$. That is to say that those are bounded in some way.

Are you probably looking for a proof that $f(X)$ is compact?